# Display NSDictionary string in UITableView

Tags: uitableview, nsdictionary, plist, unrecognized-selector

[image: My plist file]

My question is simple : how can I access to "`matchs`" dictionary and display it in a UITableView.

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

   UITableViewCell *cell = [self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier andIndexPath:indexPath];

   NSArray *myArray = [contentDictio objectForKey:@"matchs"];
   cell.textLabel.text = [[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"guest_team"];

   cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

   return cell;
}
```

Crash log : `-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x114a009c0
2014-03-15 14:34:18.127 01Foot[6089:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x114a009c0'`

Thanks :-)

Comment: where do you initialize contentDictio? please share that code as well.

Comment: Yes -> 

    
    `paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    path = [basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data-score.plist"];
    arr = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path] mutableCopy];
    contentDictio = [dict objectAtIndex: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"index"]];`

Answer (score 0):

Your screen shot shows that matchs [sic] is a Dictionary (item5) (NOTE though that item0 its an Array)  so this line...

```
NSArray *myArray = [contentDictio objectForKey:@"matchs"];
```

should be

```
NSDictonary *myDictionary = [contentDictio objectForKey:@"matchs"];
```

Then you need to work out which of the items you are a looking at in that dictionary to get at "guest_team"

You need to sort your plist out so that its consistent

Comment: Yes but now how can I access to `guest_team` ?

Comment: How is item0 defined that is an Array and your code would work. If you've created the plist make it consistent, i.e. all matchs should be Arrays

Comment: Look at the image at the top of the post, items are dictionary, matchs is a dictionary who contains multiple dictionary